# Android app crashes on intel x86 system image but works on the ARM image in the emulator

Tags: android, macos

If I try to launch my android app on an AVD with the Intel x86 system image (with emulator acceleration through Intel HAXM enabled), the app crashes with the below error,

```
07-15 14:32:46.582    1906-1913/com.x.y.android E/dalvikvm﹕ pre-allocated space for a forward jump is not big enough
07-15 14:32:46.582    1906-1913/com.x.y.android E/dalvikvm﹕ VM aborting
```

But this works fine for the ARM image. Any clues to why this is happening on the x86 image?
This happens for both API 18 and API 19 on my Mac OS X (Mountain Lion)

Comment: x86 has been noted to have issues, I would stick with ARM emulation if possible (I could be wrong about this I have just read about a lot of issues with x86 emulation).

Comment: If I remember it correctly, Genymotion actually emulates exclusively on x86. Maybe you could try with their tools? Intel also has its HAXM emulators (https://software.intel.com/es-es/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

Comment: Just read up, didn't realize Genymotion was x86 exclusive. I would also recommend Genymotion (for a lot of different types of android emulation, it is a great emulator).

Comment: Just saw the edit. Never worry, there are other resources available as well, for instance AppThwack (https://software.intel.com/es-es/android/articles/services-to-test-your-android-apps-on-intel-devices)